# How to detect if the user is pulling down in RefreshControl?

Tags: react-native

I have (horizontal) scrollable tabs, with each with a `ListView` that has a `RefreshControl`.

On iOS, it works great because the `RefreshControl` will lock the tabs from scrolling horizontally while the user is pulling down, but this doesn't happen on Android, so the horizontal scrolling of the tabs ends up intercepting the pull-down.

I could lock the tabs if I knew how to tell when the user is pulling down on the `RefreshControl`.

```
  <ListView
    ...
    refreshControl={
      <RefreshControl
        ...
        refreshing={isRefreshing}
        onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
        // but how do I actually tell when they're pulling down?
      />
    }
    ...
  />
```